# JavaScript get comma separated values based condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, ecmascript-6

Hi I'm having an issue filtering out the values from array of objects. So basically I've an array of object

```
const arr = [
    {
        "id": null,
        "name": null,
        "role": "Authorized Redistributor (AR)",
        "checked": false,
        "checkBoxPatched": true
    },
    {
        "id": null,
        "name": null,
        "role": "System Of Record (SOR)",
        "checked": true,
        "checkBoxPatched": true
    },
    {
        "id": null,
        "name": null,
        "role": "Authorized Redistributor (AR)",
        "checked": true,
        "checkBoxPatched": true
    }
]

arr.map(res => res.checked ? res.role : "").join(', ')
// ", System Of Record (SOR), Authorized Redistributor (AR)"
```

I need comma separated `role` value if `checked` is true. So from the above object the O/P should be `System Of Record (SOR), Authorized Redistributor (AR)`.

Comment: *"Tried various ways"* Then please include your attempts, we don't write code from scratch. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more info.

Comment: @Reyno Updated !. Need an help I'm getting comma at the start of the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const arr = [
    {
        "id": null,
        "name": null,
        "role": "Authorized Redistributor (AR)",
        "checked": false,
        "checkBoxPatched": true
    },
    {
        "id": null,
        "name": null,
        "role": "System Of Record (SOR)",
        "checked": true,
        "checkBoxPatched": true
    },
    {
        "id": null,
        "name": null,
        "role": "Authorized Redistributor (AR)",
        "checked": true,
        "checkBoxPatched": true
    }
]

const finalArr = arr.map(res => res.checked ? res.role : '')
  .filter((str) => str.length !== 0).join(', ');
console.log(finalArr)
```